# Java Insert Data Display on Console IDE

Tags: java, swing

Making a program which is GUI. A user can enter values in text fields and data is saved on database. But i want to display that row in which data is saved with button click on eclipse console.Just like that

```
      ========================
      title           year      
      ========================
      300             2006   

      Data Saved!
```

My code is

```
public class Db extends JFrame{


    private JTextField value1;
    private JTextField value2;

    private JLabel label1;
    private JLabel label2;

    private JButton b1;

    private  Connection conn;
    private PreparedStatement pre; 
    private ResultSet set;
    private ResultSetMetaData meta;

    String server = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/demo";
    String user="root";
    String pass="1";

    public Db(){

        super("Frame");

        getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        value1= new JTextField();
        value1.setBounds(222, 86, 128, 27);
        getContentPane().add(value1);

        value2= new JTextField();
        value2.setBounds(222, 160, 128, 27);
        getContentPane().add(value2);




        label1= new JLabel("Enter Value 1 :");
        label1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 21));
        label1.setBounds(33, 77, 146, 37);
        getContentPane().add(label1);

        label2= new JLabel("Enter Value 2 :");
        label2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 21));
        label2.setBounds(33, 151, 146, 37);
        getContentPane().add(label2);

        b1= new JButton("Save");
        b1.setBounds(161, 228, 102, 37);
        getContentPane().add(b1);
        b1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        try{

        // create our java prepared statement using a sql update query
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(server,user,pass);

        //query
         String query = "insert into movies(title,year) values (?,?)";

        //create prepared statement
          pre =      conn.prepareStatement(query);

          //parameter
          pre.setString(1, value1.getText());

          //second parameter will be integer so conversion

          String w = value2.getText();

          int p =Integer.parseInt(w);

          pre.setInt(2, p);

        // call executeUpdate to sql update statement return integer rowsaffected   
   int rowsaffect = pre.executeUpdate();

    //message come when query run     
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Query Executed Successfully");

        }
        catch(Exception e1){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1.getMessage());
        }

            }});
        setSize(450, 400);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

    }


}
```

Main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Db obj = new Db();



    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand your question correctly.
the easy way is first check does execute update successful ,if yes then print `title year` which you pass to the query .

```
int rowsaffect = pre.executeUpdate();
if(rowsaffect >0){
  System.out.println("========================");
  System.out.println("title           year");    
  System.out.println("========================");
  System.out.println(value1.getText()+"       "+p);
}
```

this an example you have to correctly add spaces to get correct output.you may need to programmatically count how much  spaces need to show output correctly because it depend on title, year value length

Comment: can we do that with ResultSetMetaData to display data on ide console

Comment: @TimAllen yes using it you can make this more dynamically .no need to hard code.you can retrieve column names dynamically

Comment: can you do that with code i don't know how to use this ResultSetMetaData and ResultSet

Comment: @TimAllen but to do so you have to use id.you insert data to database and you have id to which id you insert data and then you can use metadata to print a message.without tracking id you can't do that